# Calling Python function in XML report (odoo 10)

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to call my method which is returning values. I want to fetch the values and use them in my report.

```
@api.one
    def check_month(self,record,res):        
        fd = datetime.strptime(str(record.from_date), "%Y-%m-%d")   
        for rec in record.sales_record_ids:
            res.append(rec.jan_month)

    @api.one
    def get_sales_rec(self):
        result=[]
        target_records = self.env['sales.target'].search([('sales_team','=', self.sales_team_ids.id)])         
        for rec in target_records:
            self.check_month(rec,result)
        return result
```

like this in xml:

```
   <tbody>
        <tr t-foreach="get_sales_rec()" t-as="data">                                        
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span t-esc="data[0]" />
                </td>
            </tr>                                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Frist of all check weather your xml report is fetching the value of your any of the python's function. Because if it is not getting any of the value from any of the function then that migh be issue of your id given to xml and your particular pyhton file's model name.

Comment: I have found the help from @Heroic and resolved.

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani If you think this is the solution to you issue mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4):

Change your xml code to:

```
<tbody>
    <tr t-foreach="o.get_sales_rec()" t-as="data">                                        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span t-esc="data[0]" />
            </td>
        </tr>                                       
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here `o` stands for the report model object , so make sure you have added a python method in the same object.

Comment: Where you add python method in `sales.target` ? object

Comment: @Heroic, made a mistake. Thanks